# prevent AutoTrigger event of select2 Dropdown to call functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

**Edit :**

My Goal is that when One dropdown is selected manually , it only should set value of another dropdown , not to call its method on change event

I have 2 "select2" Dropdowns ..

```
@*Dropdown 1*@

<div >
@Html.DropDownList(Model.DDL1, new SelectList(GetCmnlSection(), "Value", "Text", Model.DDL1),new { onchange = "DDL1Operation();" })
</div>

@*Dropdown 2*@

<div >
@Html.DropDownList(Model.DDL2, new SelectList(GetCmnlSection(), "Value", "Text", Model.DDL2),new { onchange = "DDL2Operation();" })
        </div>



<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () { 
    var $ddl1 = $("select[name$=DDL1]");
        $ddl1.select2();
        var $ddl2 = $("select[name$=DDL2]");
        $ddl2.select2();
}
</script >
```

Dropdown 1 change event calls DDL1Operation() method which set values of Dropdown 2

```
function DDL1Operation() {

            $("select[name$=DDL2]").val('abc').trigger("change");

        });
```

what I want to achieve that

1. when "Dropdown 2" change manually--> DDL2Operation() should called
2. when "Dropdown 2" changes Automatically as result of "Dropdown 1" change --> DDL2Operation() should not called

I am not able to find many posts regarding "Select 2" Dropdowns. Can it be done by Some other JQuery Method ?

---

**Update**

```
 @*City Dropdown*@

 @Html.DropDownList(Model.chiefTownProp, new SelectList(GetchiefTown(), new { onchange = "PopualateFromCity();" })

 @*Commune Dropdown*@
  @Html.DropDownList(Model.communeProp, new SelectList(Getcommunes(), "Value", "Text", Model.communeId),new { onchange = "PopulateFromCommune();" })
```

and their function

```
 function PopualateFromCity() {

 $("select[name$=communeId]").val('1').trigger("change.select2");  
 }


 function PopulateFromCommune() { alert('PopulateFromCommune');}
```

---

"trigger("change.select2")"  is also not helping to stop onchange event for PopulateFromCommune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select2 does not listen to custom events on a dropdown, but you can use jQuery's event namespacing to limit the trigger scope to Select2 by triggering the *change.select2* event. You have to edit your function *DDL1Operation()* accordingly:

```
function DDL1Operation() {
    $("select[name=DDL2]").val('abc').trigger('change.select2');
}
```

Then you need to bind the onclick handlers with jquery:

```
$("select[name=DDL1]").change(function(){DDL1Operation()});
$("select[name=DDL2]").change(function(){DDL2Operation()});
```

And remove the onclick attributes from the `<select>` elements in your .NET code:

```
@*City Dropdown*@
@Html.DropDownList(Model.chiefTownProp, new SelectList(GetchiefTown())

@*Commune Dropdown*@
@Html.DropDownList(Model.communeProp, new SelectList(Getcommunes(), "Value", "Text", Model.communeId))
```

Comment: ok , so you are saying that by implementing ".trigger('change.select2');"   it will work only when DDl2 will change manually .. is it ?

Comment: `.trigger('change.select2');` will prevent the onchange event `onchange = "DDL2Operation();"` to be triggered. So if the select "DDL2" is changed manually, `DDL2Operation()` will be called, but `DDL1Operation()` will not call `DDL2Operation()` anymore.

Comment: ok , this is thing I wanted , let me work on it , and I will let you know

Comment: Nope , it is still calling onchange event of 2nd dropdown

Comment: What happens when you call this line from the JavaScript console?

Comment: didnt test console , but I updated the actual code in Bottom of first Post. Let me know if it is right implementation

Comment: Sorry, I did miss the onchange bindings should be bind by jQuery. Check my updated answer.

Comment: i was not able to try due to deadline , so I worked with flags . But I will Surely try this in next pages :)

Comment: Yes !!!! it worked like a charm , flag has too many bug due to recursve calls ., so ultimately I have to drop that idea , this is my solution . thanks